# Box shadow on list item

Tags: html, css

I have problem with displaying box-shadow on my list item. I found some similary answers here but none of them help me in my case. I try to have shadow on right and bottom of my list item, like on first example on this page http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/. Here is my list:

```
<ul id="BrosureLista">
    <li>
        <div class="BrosureListSlika">
            <img src="/images/Brosure01.jpg">
            <div class="BrosureListSlikaNaslov">
                <div>
                    <h1>CL</h1>
                    <h2>2013</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="BrosureListNaslov">
            <h2>CL 2013</h2>
            <p>vodič za hedoniste</p>
        </div>
        <div class="BrosureListDownload">
            <a href="#"><p>Download</p>                    
            <img src="/images/Download.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Ande here is css for my list:

```
#BrosureLista{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
#BrosureLista li{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding:50px 0;
    overflow:visible;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px grey;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px grey;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: you are looking for a drop shadow. for that you need to use text-shadow property

Comment: Sorry, but what's the question?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: To have shadow on right and bottom of my list item, like on first example on this page http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: So what's the problem with what you have?

Comment: Can't disply shadow on my li item.

Comment: Really? [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7bEDu/).

Comment: http://www.anaizadar.com/hr/brosure But when i put it on my page don't work, I'm trying for hours.

Comment: See, the thing is - (a) you've only got a single `li` item, (I don't know if you're expecting more than 1 shadow) but more particularly, (b) since both of your css rules specify width 100%, the list consumes 100% of the visible width, the shadow is off-screen - you don't see the shadow on the right-hand-side of it, hence you see a single shadow underneath all of the markup shown above. Remove the `width: 100%;` from each rule and observe the difference. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you give to your li 100% width. your right shadow go outside screen.
try to give less width - mayby 95-97%?